# Check the state of multiple checkboxes in nested table row using JQuery before action

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter, nested, html-table

I have a table that contains a list of recipients for gifts.  Each recipient can have one or more gifts listed for them.  I do this using a nested set of rows (one nested row in a table cell per gift) in a table cell.

Each gift has four statuses (shown through checkboxes) of Selected, Checked In, Out for Delivery, Delivered.

I need to hide the main row for the recipient when all of the checkboxes for a specific status are checked.

So, if I want to see only the recipients where a gift is not yet checked in, I would want to still see any recipients where only 1 gift may still be unchecked for 'Checked In' status.

I have the following to hide and show the rows now:

```
if (state === true) {
        switch(colId) {
            case "selectedFilter":
                $('input:checkbox.isSelected:not(:checked)').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                break;
            case "selectedFilterUnchecked":
                $('input:checkbox.isSelected:checked').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                break;
            case "checkedInFilter":
                $('input:checkbox.isCheckedIn:not(:checked)').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                break;
            case "checkedInFilterUnchecked":
                $('input:checkbox.isCheckedIn:checked').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                break;
            case "outForDeliveryFilter":
                $('input:checkbox.isOutForDelivery:not(:checked)').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                break;
            case "outForDeliveryFilterUnchecked":
                $('input:checkbox.isOutForDelivery:checked').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                break;
        }
    } else if (state === false) {
        $('table tr.trMainData:hidden').show();
    }
```

Where the 'state' is the state of a checkbox filter being clicked by the user (true or false) and 'trMainData' is the class on the main row for the recipients.

The issue is that if I set only 1 gift out of 2 as Checked In, then the entire recipient row is hidden, including the gift that has not yet been checked in.

Any help and suggestions, as always are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's something about posting my question that then give's me a bright idea.  Not sure this is the best, or right way, but it's working.

Here's what I did.

```
if (state === true) {
        switch(colId) {
            case "selectedFilter":
                $('input:checkbox.isSelected:not(:checked)').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                $('input:checkbox.isSelected:checked:hidden').closest('.trMainData').show();
                break;
            case "selectedFilterUnchecked":
                $('input:checkbox.isSelected:checked').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                $('input:checkbox.isSelected:not(:checked):hidden').closest('.trMainData').show();
                break;
            case "checkedInFilter":
                $('input:checkbox.isCheckedIn:not(:checked)').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                $('input:checkbox.isCheckedIn:checked:hidden').closest('.trMainData').show();
                break;
            case "checkedInFilterUnchecked":
                $('input:checkbox.isCheckedIn:checked').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                $('input:checkbox.isCheckedIn:not(:checked):hidden').closest('.trMainData').show();
                break;
            case "outForDeliveryFilter":
                $('input:checkbox.isOutForDelivery:not(:checked)').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                $('input:checkbox.isOutForDelivery:checked:hidden').closest('.trMainData').show();
                break;
            case "outForDeliveryFilterUnchecked":
                $('input:checkbox.isOutForDelivery:checked').closest('.trMainData').hide();
                $('input:checkbox.isOutForDelivery:not(:checked):hidden').closest('.trMainData').show();
                break;
        }
    } else if (state === false) {
        $('table tr.trMainData:hidden').show();
    }
```

So, essentially, first I hide every row that has even 1 item checked for the column I'm filtering by.  Then I search through those hidden columns, and show any of them that have an item that should be shown, and re-show it...basically filtering twice, but it's working.